# Error The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8' while executing webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am getting a runtime time error while executing the following web api method

```
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

web api controller

```
[Route("api/movies")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var movies = _movieBusiness.GetAllMovies();
    return Ok(movies);
}
```

Business logic method

```
public List<Movie> GetAllMovies()
        {
            var movies = _movieRepository.GetMovies();
            _unitOfWork.Dispose();
            return movies;
        }
```

Data access method

```
public List<Movie> GetMovies()
        {
            var query = "dbo.spGetMovies";
            var list = SqlMapper.Query<Movie>(_unitOfWork.GetConnection(), query, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return list;

        }
```

Comment: Is there an inner exception with more details about why the object failed to serialize?

Comment: Error while copying content to a stream.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed. The reason is the assembly in the DTO project had an outdated Newtonsoft.json dll. Updating the DLL worked for me.